# Issues with media queries CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

Our team is new to responsive design and is trying to code with a mobile first framework.  We're trying to use media queries to scale up in screen size, but can't seem to get it to work correctly.  This is what our CSS looks like so far:

```
.flex, .cards, .card {
  display: flex;
}

.flex {
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.cards, .card {
  align-items:center;
}

.cards {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: $color-lightest;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 22px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .cards {
    width: 49%;
    margin: 1%;  
  }

  .cards:nth-of-type(even) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }

  .cards:nth-of-type(odd) {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .cards {
    width: 32%;
    margin: 1%;
  }

  .cards:nth-of-type(3n) {
    margin-right: 0;
  }

  .cards:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

The result of this looks like this when we set the screen size to exactly 1024px:

[image]

When we inspect the div, it looks like both the media queries css for 480px and 1024px are firing.  What are we doing incorrect here?

EDIT:  adding HTML

```
<div class="flex" ng-init="init(user.sys_id)">
  <div  class="cards" ng-repeat="task in data.tasks | orderBy: ['order']" >
    <div  class="card" ng-click="c.onWidget(task);">
      <i ng-if="task.finished" class="{{task.icon}} fa-5x card-img finished" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i ng-if="!task.finished && task.isOverDue" class="{{task.icon}} fa-5x card-img overdue" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i ng-if="!task.finished && !task.isOverDue" class="{{task.icon}} fa-5x card-img pending" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <div class="card-content">
        <h4>
          <!--<a href="?id=hri_task_details&table=sn_hr_core_task&sys_id={{task.sys_id}}" id="task_{{$index}}">{{::task.short_description}}</a>-->
          <a ng-click="">{{::task.short_description}}</a>
        </h4>
        <span ng-if="!task.finished">
          <span class="text-normal" ng-if="task.due_date">${Due by} {{::task.due_date | date: 'mediumDate' }}
            <span class="text-warning" ng-if="task.isOverDue"> (${Overdue})</span>
          </span>
        </span>
        <span ng-if="task.finished" class="text-muted">${Completed at} {{::task.closed_at | date: 'mediumDate'}}</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <i alt="${Open}" ng-if="!task.finished && task.isOverDue" class="m-l-sm fa fa-square-o fa-2x overdue"></i>
        <i alt="${Open}" ng-if="!task.finished && !task.isOverDue" class="m-l-sm fa fa-square-o fa-2x pending"></i>
        <i alt="${Completed}" ng-if="task.finished" class="m-l-sm fa fa-check-square-o fa-2x finished"></i>
      </div>   
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap or any other responsive framework? Also, would you mind supplying your HTML as well?

Comment: yes i'm using bootstrap, let me add the html.  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your first media query to this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 1023.99px) {
    ...
}
```

`.cards:nth-of-type(3n)` and `.cards:nth-of-type(even)` seem to both be applied.

Comment: Thanks nickfindley!  this works, but is it best practice to list min and max screen sizes in the media query?  We've thought about doing this, but many of the tutorials online do not explicitly say between x screen size and y screen size.  Am just wondering what's the best practice of writing these media queries.

Comment: @Dave yes, there is no problem using both. That's why there is min and max.

Answer (score 1):

Should the "min-width: 480px" be "max-width: 480px"?

As the CSS is currently defined, once the screen hits the 1024px width, then both min-width conditions are enabled along with the applicable CSS definitions.

Comment: Thanks JohnH, actually we want screen widths between 480px - 1024px to be two columns and screen widths of 1024px and beyond to be 3 columns